# VBA: incompatible with .NET regex balancing groups?

Tags: .net, regex, vba, porting, balancing-groups

I have been checking around as to whether I can use .NET regex balancing groups in an excel spreadsheet VBA function.

However, it appears that VBA is not compatible with, nor is it a part of .NET. For example, wikipedia bluntly states that ["VBA is incompatible with Visual Basic .NET (VB.NET)".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications#Language)

So, just to be sure, w/r/t regex balancing groups, I'm out of luck in VBA, correct?

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with writing a .NET object, exposing it to COM and using it from VBA.

"Incompatible" probably means the .NET code, pasted into a VBA editor, will not work.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually use .Net to create Visual Studio solutions since at least Office 2003 using [Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx) (VSTO).

Unfortunately, you have to jump through a couple of hoops and adhere to some restrictions to get it deployed, but it could potentially be easier than exposing and registering a COM object. [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa192490%28v=office.11%29.aspx) has some good information about creation and deployment of VSTO solutions.